# Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY in CODEIGNITER - Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM videos
WHERE Autor = 'LittleBabyBum ® Español'
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 10)
UNION (
SELECT *
FROM videos
WHERE Categoría = 'Música - Niños'
  AND Autor <>'LittleBabyBum ® Español'
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 5
```

And it works really good.

But actually I'm with problems to use in codeigniter ... someone knows how to use it?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - We're here to help, not to write code for you. Show us what you've tried so far and we'll help you.

Comment: Was answered, thanks for suggetions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in model:

```
function result() {
    $query = $this->db->query("(SELECT * FROM videos where Autor = 'LittleBabyBum ® Español' order by RAND() LIMIT 10) UNION (SELECT * FROM videos WHERE Categoría = 'Música - Niños' AND Autor <>'LittleBabyBum ® Español' order by RAND() lIMIT 5)");
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

In controller:

```
$array = $this->MyModel->result();
```

Comment: If I helped you - please mark my answer as useful. Press Up arrow.